# Temporary and static realm objects used together?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

I am currently running into some issues regarding the realm database and I don't know what the best practices are to tackle this problem.

So I have setup an app which communicates to a server and gets Post Objects through Retrofit stored into my Realm. This post feed is a core part of my app and I want to keep things locally to stay attractive while being offline. The thing is that I cannot store the entire feed list locally as this would be a massive chunk of memory. But I want to make sure that the User gets this content while scrolling through a recycler-view.
The recycler-view currently only shows local Posts and updates them if refresh is forced. I want to implement a load on scroll mecanism that loads Post objects into it while scrolling but this scroll objects should **not** be stored locally when the app closes.

I thought of creating an additionally in-memory Realm but there is another problem: A Post Object contains a ForeignKey to a UserObject. When I download this dynamic PostObjects and a UserObject changed over this time on the server I want to be able to reflect this changes to every other User on the local persisten Realm too. (To avoid having 2 different UserObjects for the same User)

My best idea i came up so far is to have a 
Boolean field on the PostObjects set to true or false to indicate temporary state or not. After the applications closes I would drop all the temporary entries. Is this a viable solution or do I miss anything? I hope you understand my problem and can help.

**Edit:** My Realm Database contains two relevant objects:

1. User

Has a name (primarykey), id (global from server), imageUrls etc..

2. Post

Has a User who created it, again an id and its data (text, date, images...)

**Edit2 :** What I really need is a type of in-memory Realm that allows me on start up to clone another realm that is used to have data in case of no connectivity. Before the in-memory realm gets deleted I would then override the offline realm with the 5-10 last post entries of the temporary realm. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: I kinda lost it at the userobject.

Comment: I am sorry I know it's kind a mess..  I will edit it just a second..

Comment: "the thing is that I cannot store the entire feed list locally as this would be a massive chunk of memory" By this do you mean memory or disk? Because Realm will allow you to load a RealmResult with many thousands and more objects without problems. It would only use memory for the objects actually visible on screen

Comment: The User can't have a full copy of their feed saved locally because that would result soon in a lot of occupied memory. Basically i want to implement a Facebook like feed that keeps the last important feed entries stored locally in case of offline access. Is realm the right choice?

Comment: That question is not a question about "Realm or not" but more about "Database or not". If you want to store a feed offline, all databases can do that for you. If you really meant you only wanted to save the last 5-10 items, than you are shooting birds with cannons, because then it would probably be easier to just save the JSON to disk. However with a database (and Realm) you would be able to save 100's or 1000's of feed items for a much better offline experience.

Comment: Yeah thats right and I thought of implementing this option too but I got really into the workflow with Realm and updating UI as soon as new Data is present. Doing something like update(User user) which fetches data into the old User object and gets automatically notified...

How would i implement an automatic offline safe when the application finishes? I am really curious how apps like Instagram have implemented their behaviour..